# airmon-ng not working in terminal (command not found)

Tags: macos, aircrack-ng

I successfully installed aircrack-ng using macports (i know it worked because when i enter aircrack-ng in terminal it shows the version and options) on my macbook pro. However when I use the airmon-ng command i get "command not found."

Comment: Show the output of it working and not working... it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: mynames-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ airmon-ng


-bash: airmon-ng: command not found

Comment: When I enter "airmon-ng" in the command line I get "command not found." Thats all. Based on the tutorial I am following I should be getting a list of wireless interfaces. https://github.com/brannondorsey/wifi-cracking

Comment: Re: "when i enter aircrack-ng in terminal it shows the version and options", so how is it not working?

Comment: airCRACK-ng and airMON-ng are two different commands. aircrack works (shows that its installed) while airmon does not

Comment: I have since found this post on the aircrack forums. (https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php/topic,1460.0.html) it says the airmon command isn't in the mac os version. however i have so far been unable to find this information in the documentation so I am not sure how I (or other users) are supposed to know this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that they were two different commands.  I think you are correct that `airmon-ng` isn't on the macOS version — only on the linux version (I just downloaded and compiled the from source and it's only reference shows up in `linux.c`. https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know, you can't use `airmon-ng` on MacOs, they're for Linux only.
The best way I can suggest for you is using `sudo airport -s` to determine which SSID and its channel you want to attack, after that, `sudo airport en0 sniff x` to capture packages of all SSIDs which located at channel x, en0 or en1 is the wifi setting of your mac, you can go to "About this mac -> System Report -> Network ->
Wifi -> BSD Device name" to check out.

For example you want to capture packages from all SSIDs or from your determined SSID which have channel 6 `sudo airport en0 sniff 6`.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Even if one is doing it running VM with Debain?

Comment: I recommend NO, because VM does not see the built in wifi card of your laptop as a wifi adapter, but will see it as an ethernet adapter. You still stay connected to internet but package injection and monitor mode is for wifi card only.